# Angular TRANSLOCO library change currency symbol

Tags: angular, angularjs, transloco

I am going through the Angular Transloco library https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/, I have successfully installed and tried the examples https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/docs/plugins/locale/ all worked as expected. For example

```
<span>
   {{ 1000000 | translocoCurrency: 'symbol' : { minimumFractionDigits: 0 } }}
</span>
```

returns `$1,000,000`

Now I want to change or localise the currency from `$` to let's say the Nigerian currency `(NGN)` but I can't find a way of doing this. I have gone through the documentation but that wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TranslocoCurrencyPipe, the next parameter after 'symbol' is the currency code.

So you should do like this:

```
<span>
   {{ 1000000 | translocoCurrency: 'symbol' : { minimumFractionDigits: 0 }: 'NGN' }}
</span>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Kalas, thanks for the contribution, this worked?